# ArcObjects WPF Select layer in legend

Tags: arcgis-10.2, layers, select, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

Can I select a layer, by code, in the TOC/legend of a map in a WPF ArcGIS Runtime application?

I develope in ArcGIS Runtime SDK 10.2.2 for .Net in C#.

Comment: The .NET ArcGIS Runtime does not use ArcObjects, it uses its own .NET SDK (that is built on top of ArcObjects).  That being said, have a look at the Layers namespace in the API Documentation: https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference/

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

There is a property named IsSelected in ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.Primitives.LegendItemViewModel class, so I had to find my layer by service and sublayerId and set this property to true.

```
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.Primitives.LegendItemViewModel layer = ControlObjMap.Control.Object.LegendExtension.BusquedaItemSublayerId(leyenda.LayerItems, layerService, layerIndex);
            if (layer != null)
                layer.IsSelected = true;


    public static ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.Primitives.LegendItemViewModel BusquedaItemSublayerId(
        this IEnumerable<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.Primitives.LayerItemViewModel> layerItems,string serviceName, int sublayerId)
    {
        if (layerItems == null)
            return null;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.Primitives.LegendItemViewModel layer = null;

        foreach (var layerItem in layerItems)
        {
            if (layerItem.LayerItems != null)
            {
                layer = layerItem.LayerItems.BusquedaItemSublayerId(serviceName, sublayerId);
            }
            else if ((layerItem.Layer is ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer || layerItem.Layer is ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer) && 
                layerItem.SubLayerID == sublayerId)
            {
                if ((layerItem.Layer is ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.DynamicMapServiceLayer && ((ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer)layerItem.Layer).Url == serviceName)||
                    (layerItem.Layer is ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer && ((ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer)layerItem.Layer).Url == serviceName)
                    )
                    layer = layerItem;
            }

            if (layer != null)
                return layer;
        }

        return null;
    }
```